# Create man pages for my own C library

Tags: c, comments, manpage

In some C-source file I've seen comments in the format:

```
/**
 *  @bla bla bla
 *  bla bla..
 */
```

Someone told me that if I comment my `.c` / `.h` files properly, then with a certain tool I can autogenerate man pages from those files automatically.

Does anybody know if this is possible? (How to do, which software should I use, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are searching for [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Those comments you see are probably [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) markup. That can produce man, HTML, and a variety of other formats.

Answer (score 2):

Try doxygen

http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html

The syntax you showed is doxygen.  AFAIK, it can generate man pages (and HTML and LaTeX).